# When will app reviewed from apple after rejection of app due to metadata rejection?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, apple-store

I have submitted my app on August 20th for apple review. But my app was rejected by apple on 29th of august due to metadata rejection .On 30th of august again I  have submitted my app for review..

So My question is when will apple reviews app usually, if submitted after rejection.

Any help is appreciated

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, a metadata resubmission takes less than a day.

But that is extremely misleading.

Many think you have to resubmit after correcting the data. This is wrong. Clicking "Submit for Review" puts your app in the back of the queue. Meaning it will take another week or so.

The correct way is to reply to the resolution center message saying you corrected the error. Follow [this](http://www.brynbodayle.com/an-easy-mistake-with-itunes-connect-metadata-rejections/) guide for details.

Comment: thank you for the response.. I have just updated the details for review in app preview notes as apple has guided.not submitted a new binary..But it is almost 3 days still my app is in waiting for review..

Comment: Can I contact to apple through support for speed of app review process?Can I do Like this or will apple reject my app if I ask for app expedite review?

Comment: You can ask for expedite review. It depends on the reasons you provide. If you have an existing app that you have just released 3 days ago and you have bug fix then this is valid reason. Or your marketings efforts are set (valid webpage, reviews almost showing up). Otherwise -> reject because you don't need to be expedited.

Comment: Like @xhruso00 said, you can request an expedited review request, but unless it is backed by a valid(important) reason, you won't get it approved. Usually, big companies have more leverage on this. You will have to wait out the remained of the week to get it approved because app review notes are read only when it begins the review process, never before. Of course, the review team will have a quicker "in review" when you tell them you only changed metadata, not the actual binary.

Comment: Wow, I've been doing it wrong all these years. Have you done this anytime since 10/15 and had success? The guide you link to has updated and suggests clicking the *Submit for Review* button.